# Display curl output in readable JSON format in Unix shell script

Tags: json, shell, curl

In my Unix shell script, when I execute a curl command, the result will be displayed as below which I am redirecting to file:

```
{"type":"Show","id":"123","title":"name","description":"Funny","channelTitle":"ifood.tv","lastUpdateTimestamp":"2014-04-20T20:34:59","numOfVideos":"15"}
```

But, I want this output to put in the readable JSON format like below in the file:

```
{"type":"Show",
"id":"123",
"title":"name",
"description":"Funny",
"channelTitle":"ifood.tv",
"lastUpdateTimestamp":"2014-04-20T20:34:59",
"numOfVideos":"15"}
```

How do I format the output this way?

Answer (score 785):

A few solutions to choose from:

> [`json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json) json is a fast CLI tool for working with JSON. It is a single-file node.js script with no external deps (other than `node.js` itself).

```sh
$ echo '{"type":"Bar","id":"1","title":"Foo"}' | json
{
  "type": "Bar",
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Foo"
}
```

Require:

```
# npm install -g json
```

---

> [json_pp](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/json_pp/): command utility available in Linux systems for JSON decoding/encoding

```sh
echo '{"type":"Bar","id":"1","title":"Foo"}' | json_pp -json_opt pretty,canonical
{
   "id" : "1",
   "title" : "Foo",
   "type" : "Bar"
}
```

You may want to keep the `-json_opt pretty,canonical` argument for predictable ordering.

---

> [jq](/questions/tagged/jq): lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor. It is written in portable C, and it has zero runtime dependencies.

```sh
echo '{"type":"Bar","id":"1","title":"Foo"}' | jq '.'
{
  "type": "Bar",
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Foo"
}
```

The simplest `jq` program is the expression `.`, which takes the input and produces it unchanged as output.

For additional `jq` options check [the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters)

---

> [python yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) yq: Command-line YAML/XML/TOML processor - jq wrapper for YAML, XML, TOML documents

```sh
$ echo '{"type":"Bar","id":"1","title":"Foo"}' | yq
{
  "type": "Bar",
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Foo"
}
```

The [go](/questions/tagged/go) version [go yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) doesn't work here

---

> With [xidel](https://github.com/benibela/xidel) Command line tool to download and extract data from HTML/XML pages or JSON-APIs, using CSS, XPath 3.0, XQuery 3.0, JSONiq or pattern matching. It can also create new or transformed XML/HTML/JSON documents.

```sh
$ echo '{"type":"Bar","id":"1","title":"Foo"}' | xidel -e '$json'
{
  "type": "Bar",
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Foo"
}
```

---

with [python](/questions/tagged/python):

```sh
echo '{"type":"Bar","id":"1","title":"Foo"}' | python -m json.tool
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Foo",
    "type": "Bar"
}
```

---

with [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```sh
echo '{"type":"Bar","id":"1","title":"Foo"}' | node -p "JSON.stringify( JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(0) ), 0, 1 )"
{
 "type": "Bar",
 "id": "1",
 "title": "Foo"
}
```

Comment: is this the way ?curl -i -vs -X POST -H "$SESSION_TOKEN" -H "$AUTH_TOKEN" -H "Accept:$ACCEPT_HEADER" -H "Content-Type:text/plain" "http://$BASE_URI/api" | json_pp >> jsonoutput.json

Comment: Absolutely. Have you tested ?

Comment: yes, but nothing been written to the file "jsonoutput.json". Its size is zero.

Comment: `json_pp` seems to format data in reverse order than it's expected. Is there a way to un-reverse data?

Comment: +1 for the bash and node.js portion. I was trying to do something different (pipe JSON data into node.js). I was able to do this via `cat` and node using `cat ./example.json | node <<< "var o = $(cat); console.log(o);"` Worked like a charm

Comment: jq is great. can you explain why you added the 'dot' at the end ? ('jq .')

Comment: json_pp is a Perl command utility which converts between some input and output formats (one of them JSON). The default input format is json and the default output format is json with pretty option.

Comment: How to do this with c++

Comment: Pipe to Python for the win !

Comment: I like the jq solution, but may I know what's the purpose of the quotes around the period?

Comment: @Jams, the command your wrote above worked for me on Mac, it outputs a full json file, you may need to specify the output argument explicitly to `json` like so: `curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 | json_pp -f json -t json > todo.json` this outputs `todo.json` for me.

Answer (score 100):

I am guessing that you want to prettify the JSON output.
That could be achieved using python:

```
curl http://localhost:8880/test.json | python -mjson.tool > out.json
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But i am not using Python, im using shell. can  u guide me on shell

Comment: @Jams that executes python from the shell giving your a pretty printed output.

Comment: Great solution as python comes preinstalled.

Comment: That python script gives a "broken pipe" error when I add a " | head" to it.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten I don't see that problem myself (maybe different versions), but that may be due to the `head` command cutting off the output being piped to it before reaching the end, thus "breaking" the pipe. If you allow `head` to consume the entire data stream from the pipe, I'd expect the error to not show up.

Comment: Best thing about this solution is that Python comes pre-installed. This is specially helpful for the places where you have no control over the applications that are installed in the system (e.g. You are not in sudo users' list)

Answer (score 62):

This is to add to of Gilles' Answer. There are many ways to get this done but personally I prefer something lightweight, easy to remember and universally available (e.g. come with standard LTS installations of your preferred Linux flavor or easy to install) on common *nix systems.

Here are the options in their preferred order:

**Python Json.tool module**

```
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | python -mjson.tool
```

> pros: almost available everywhere; cons: no color coding

---

**jq (may require one time installation)**

```
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | jq
```

> cons: needs to install jq; pros: color coding and versatile

---

**json_pp (available in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)**

```
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | json_pp
```

---

**For Ruby users**

```
gem install jsonpretty
echo '{"foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum"}' | jsonpretty
```

Comment: Thanks @zhenhua!  I used  `cat myFile.json | python -mjson.tool >> myFilePretty.json` then opened in my editor (vim, don't hate) and got colors.

Answer (score 45):

You can use [the *json* node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json):

`npm i -g json`

then simply append `| json` after curl.
`curl http://localhost:8880/test.json | json`

Comment: I would remove the comment and part about sudo if you don't recommend it haha. I agree it's not necessary. Thanks for the answer

Comment: If you don't want to install the `json` module, you could use it directly with `npx`:
`curl http://localhost:8880/test.json | npx json`

Comment: this should be the accepted response IMO, this is the easiest way to go. no options required, outputs exactly what you'd expect

Answer (score 39):

You can install jq and make the query like below:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/observations/station/221 | jq
```

[image]

Comment: why do I get command not found when I use it like this but not when I just run jq without anything else?

Comment: @AhmedHasn. What OS do you use? Anyways, irrespective of that, you will need to install the jq and it should work.

Comment: RHEL7 but as I said jq is installed and it works if I don't use it in a pipe

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what's the issue then.

Comment: This is the simplest, to-the-point answer. Install jq tool in Linux and jq is used in many cases.

Comment: works on windows too

Answer (score 29):

```
python -m json.tool
Curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/people/api.json | python -m json.tool
```

can also help.

Answer (score 19):

I found json_reformat to be very handy. So I just did the following:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/people/api.json | json_reformat
```

that's it!

Comment: If using Ubuntu you can find json_reformat in the yajl-tools package.

Comment: In fedora 25 it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

**Motivation:** You want to print prettify JSON response after curl command request.

**Solution**:  [***json_pp***](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/JSON-PP/bin/json_pp) - commandline tool that converts between some input and output formats (one of them is JSON). This program was copied from json_xs and modified. The default input format is json and the default output format is json with pretty option.

**Synposis**:
 `json_pp [-v] [-f from_format] [-t to_format] [-json_opt options_to_json1[,options_to_json2[,...]]]`

**Formula**: `<someCommand> | json_pp`

**Example**:

**Request**

```
curl -X https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 | json_pp
```

**Response**

```
{
   "completed" : false,
   "id" : 1,
   "title" : "delectus aut autem",
   "userId" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Check out [curljson](https://github.com/mitnk/curljson)

```
$ pip install curljson
$ curljson -i <the-json-api-url>
```

Answer (score 5):

A lot more features (slice, filter and map and transform structured ) apart from formatting.

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5' | jq '.[0]'
```

```
{
  "sha": "d25341478381063d1c76e81b3a52e0592a7c997f",
  "commit": {
    "author": {
      "name": "Stephen Dolan",
      "email": "mu@netsoc.tcd.ie",
      "date": "2013-06-22T16:30:59Z"
    },
    "committer": {
      "name": "Stephen Dolan",
      "email": "mu@netsoc.tcd.ie",
      "date": "2013-06-22T16:30:59Z"
    },
    "message": "Merge pull request #162 from stedolan/utf8-fixes\n\nUtf8 fixes. Closes #161",
    "tree": {
      "sha": "6ab697a8dfb5a96e124666bf6d6213822599fb40",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/git/trees/6ab697a8dfb5a96e124666bf6d6213822599fb40"
    },
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/git/commits/d25341478381063d1c76e81b3a52e0592a7c997f",
    "comment_count": 0
  },
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits/d25341478381063d1c76e81b3a52e0592a7c997f",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/d25341478381063d1c76e81b3a52e0592a7c997f",
  "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits/d25341478381063d1c76e81b3a52e0592a7c997f/comments",
  "author": {
    "login": "stedolan",
    "id": 79765,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/79765?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/stedolan",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "committer": {
    "login": "stedolan",
    "id": 79765,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/79765?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/stedolan",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/stedolan/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "parents": [
    {
      "sha": "54b9c9bdb225af5d886466d72f47eafc51acb4f7",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits/54b9c9bdb225af5d886466d72f47eafc51acb4f7",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/54b9c9bdb225af5d886466d72f47eafc51acb4f7"
    },
    {
      "sha": "8b1b503609c161fea4b003a7179b3fbb2dd4345a",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits/8b1b503609c161fea4b003a7179b3fbb2dd4345a",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/8b1b503609c161fea4b003a7179b3fbb2dd4345a"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
curl <...> | xidel - -se '$json'
```

`xidel` can probably retrieve the JSON for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

In real cases sometimes you need use `-i` option in curl to get headers

```
$ curl https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/1 -i
HTTP/2 200 
date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 16:46:39 GMT
content-type: application/json
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, api_key, Authorization
server: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)

{"id":1,"category":{"id":0,"name":"zbyszek"},"name":"pies","photoUrls":["string"],"tags":[{"id":0,"name":"pies"}],"status":"available"}
```

in that case, pure jq/json_pp/json_reformat will fail:

```
curl https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/1 -i | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   138    0   138    0     0    108      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--   109
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 7
```

I offer to use ijq https://github.com/1frag/ijq that ignores non-json lines

```
curl https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/1 -i | ijq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    51    0    51    0     0     41      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--    41
HTTP/2 404 
date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 16:51:58 GMT
content-type: application/json
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, api_key, Authorization
server: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "Pet not found",
    "type": "error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install

```bash
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
$ sudo pip install curljson
```

then using, example:

```bash
$ curljson -i localhost:9080/actuator/health ; echo
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 15 Sep 2023 10:28:55 GMT

{
    "status": "UP"
}
```

Tested with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS .

Answer (score 0):

If you use mac's terminal, `jq` is built-in and you don't need to install anything. Just append `| jq` to your `CURL` command and you will get the formatted json. An example:
When you execute this:

```
curl http://time.jsontest.com/ | jq
```

you will get this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   100  100   100    0     0    388      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   389
{
  "date": "12-28-2023",
  "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1703738250474,
  "time": "04:37:30 AM"
}
```

Comment: Please don’t post duplicate answers.