# Is there a way to beautify curl command in Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've a complex curl command that I want to analyze but it's all minfied into one line. Is there a formatter that would beautify it?

Answer (score 1):

[shell-format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=foxundermoon.shell-format) can format `bash` files. Assuming you put that `curl` command to be part of a `bash` script, it should work.

Comment: for some reason it keeps saying: not found! please install manual https://mvdan.cc/sh/cmd/shfmt

Comment: Well, did you install the tool?

Comment: yes, and i think it didn't properly set path variables. that's a big jump from installing extension to having to install a separate tool and configure path env vars. So im looking for something else if i dont find an extension then ill try again with this.

Comment: Most extensions related to formatting rely on external tools, I doubt you'll find one that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl http://example.com/api/getPosts | node <<< "var o = $(cat); console.log(JSON.stringify(o, null, 4));"
```

Got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27238477/2159159