# How to make the output of cURL pretty

Tags: curl

This appears to be a perennial problem, given the number of similar questions and dearth of solutions.

The output of cURL isn't well formed json to begin with, so how can this be made to work:

```
% curl -s https://www.medium.com | jq 
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 7
```

Comment: This page has some ideas, but the results were marginal at best: https://akrabat.com/pretty-print-curl-i/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, curl does *not* return you any kind of JSON *per se*. You'll have to adress the JSON-API of a site to get some JSON to prettify.

Compare the output of

```
curl -s https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
```

and

```
curl -s https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/
```

I suppose you see the difference. Therefore pipelining the first to `jq` won't yield anything useful, but pipeling the second will.

```
curl -s https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/ | jq
```

Prettily prettified, isn't it?

For further inspiration I recommend the Stackoverflow thread -- including comments! -- on how to [display curl output in readable json format in unix shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238411/display-curl-output-in-readable-json-format-in-unix-shell-script).

*Edit:* A better example to demonstrate the prettification (thx to [jQueeny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21972629/jqueeny)). Adressing the JSON API under [api.joind.in](https://api.joind.in) without `jq`:

```
~ $ curl -s https://api.joind.in
{"events":"https:\/\/api.joind.in\/v2.1\/events","hot-events":"https:\/\/api.joind.in\/v2.1\/events?filter=hot","upcoming-events":"https:\/\/api.joind.in\/v2.1\/events?filter=upcoming","past-events":"https:\/\/api.joind.in\/v2.1\/events?filter=past","open-cfps":"https:\/\/api.joind.in\/v2.1\/events?filter=cfp","docs":"http:\/\/joindin.github.io\/joindin-api\/"}
```

With `jq` (actually even colored):

```
~ $ curl -s https://api.joind.in | jq
{
  "events": "https://api.joind.in/v2.1/events",
  "hot-events": "https://api.joind.in/v2.1/events?filter=hot",
  "upcoming-events": "https://api.joind.in/v2.1/events?filter=upcoming",
  "past-events": "https://api.joind.in/v2.1/events?filter=past",
  "open-cfps": "https://api.joind.in/v2.1/events?filter=cfp",
  "docs": "http://joindin.github.io/joindin-api/"
}
```

Comment: I have up-voted this answer because is demonstrates that jq is a perfectly good option for pretty printing a JSON API.

Answer (score 2):

**Pretty Print HTML/XML**

You can use [HTML Tidy](https://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/tidylib_api_5.6.0/index.html) to read from stdin. This package is used for fixing HTML mark-up and gives error reporting on malformed HTML. However, one of the features of this package is that is comes with a lot of default settings that fix the markup on output. So if you just want to output a pretty version of HTML then you will need to unset some of these default settings which can be found [here](https://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/tidylib_api_5.6.0/tidy_quickref.html#punctuation-wrap).

Install tidy:

```bash
sudo apt install tidy
```

Pipe cURL to tidy to output pretty:

```bash
curl -s https://www.w3.org/html/ | tidy --drop-empty-paras no --drop-empty-elements no --show-warnings no -i -quiet
```

**Pretty Print JSON**

As @Krokomot has already pointed out. If the API responds with just JSON data then jq will pretty print the cURL request just fine as long as you use the `-s` option to silence any errors:

Install jq:

```bash
sudo apt install jq
```

Pipe cURL to tidy then to jq:

```bash
curl -s https://api.joind.in | jq
```

**Pretty Print JSON if API returns malformed JSON**

HTML Tidy comes with an option that outputs only the body of the HTTP response `[--show-body-only yes]` and can remove any formatted wrapping that jq doesn't like. That can then be piped to jq like so:

Install jq:

Pipe cURL to tidy then to jq:

```bash
curl -s https://api.joind.in | tidy --show-body-only yes --wrap 0 -quiet | jq
```

Comment: One gets exactly the same result without `tidy` in your example, so just `curl -s https://api.joind.in | jq`. The point is to adress a JSON API, and not an arbitrary URL as the OP tried.

Comment: If the web API responds with JSON anyway, than `tidy` is of no use.

Comment: I need a better example of an api that fails with jq. Thank you for pointing this out. JSON will always be sent in the body of a HTTP response so tidy can always be used to select only the body of that response. Tidy is being used here as middleman to pipe the JSON so is of great use.

Comment: I'm aware, that the JSON is in the body of the HTTP response. What I mean is, that this is already considered by `curl`. Look at `curl -s https://api.joind.in`. That already returns you JSON, though not prettified. If one would need `tidy` after adressing a *JSON API* to clean up *HTML* related stuff, than already `curl` failed, and not `jq`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The `-s` option of `curl` silences any errors before piping to jq so if it is a well maintained JSON API the jq will have no issues reading the curl output.

Answer (score 1):

this would prettify both JSON and HTML:

```
curl whatever | php -r '$in=stream_get_contents(STDIN);$decoded=@json_decode($in,true,512,0);if(json_last_error()===JSON_ERROR_NONE){echo json_encode($decoded,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);exit(0);}$decoded=new DOMDocument();if(@$decoded->loadHTML($in,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD|LIBXML_NOBLANKS|LIBXML_NONET)){$decoded->formatOutput=true;$decoded->preserveWhiteSpace=false;$decoded->normalizeDocument();echo $decoded->saveXML();exit(0);}echo $in;'
```

eg

```
$ curl -s https://api.joind.in | php -r '$in=stream_get_contents(STDIN);$decoded=@json_decode($in,true,512,0);if(json_last_error()===JSON_ERROR_NONE){echo json_encode($decoded,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);exit(0);}$decoded=new DOMDocument();if(@$decoded->loadHTML($in,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD|LIBXML_NOBLANKS|LIBXML_NONET)){$decoded->formatOutput=true;$decoded->preserveWhiteSpace=false;$decoded->normalizeDocument();echo $decoded->saveXML();exit(0);}echo $in;'
{
    "events": "https://api.joind.in/v2.1/events",
    "hot-events": "https://api.joind.in/v2.1/events?filter=hot",
    "upcoming-events": "https://api.joind.in/v2.1/events?filter=upcoming",
    "past-events": "https://api.joind.in/v2.1/events?filter=past",
    "open-cfps": "https://api.joind.in/v2.1/events?filter=cfp",
    "docs": "http://joindin.github.io/joindin-api/"
}
$ curl -sL https://google.com | php -r '$in=stream_get_contents(STDIN);$decoded=@json_decode($in,true,512,0);if(json_last_error()===JSON_ERROR_NONE){echo json_encode($decoded,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);exit(0);}$decoded=new DOMDocument();if(@$decoded->loadHTML($in,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD|LIBXML_NOBLANKS|LIBXML_NONET)){$decoded->formatOutput=true;$decoded->preserveWhiteSpace=false;$decoded->normalizeDocument();echo $decoded->saveXML();exit(0);}echo $in;'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="no">
  <head>
    <meta content="Velkommen til Google Søk. Finn det du leter etter på nettet på et blunk." name="description"/>
    <meta content="noodp" name="robots"/>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"/>
    <title>Google</title>
    <script nonce="ob11PMaHjryfyuNi-6r3MQ">
    (...)
```

but better yet, make a `pretty` with chmod a+x in /usr/local/bin (or anywhere in your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) with

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
$in=stream_get_contents(STDIN);
$decoded = @json_decode($in, true, 512, 0);
if(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    /* json detected */
    echo json_encode($decoded, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
    exit(0);
}
$decoded = new DOMDocument();
if(@$decoded->loadHTML($in, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NOBLANKS | LIBXML_NONET)){
    /* HTML detected */
    $decoded->formatOutput = true;
    $decoded->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $decoded->normalizeDocument();
    echo $decoded->saveXML();
    exit(0);
}
/* unknown format, print as is */
echo $in;
```

and simply do

```
curl whatever | pretty
```